# Как растянуть svg маску по высоте?

Tags: html, css, svg, inkscape

Изображение обрезается, как растянуть svg маску по высоте?

[Оригинал](https://jsfiddle.net/ktkn6o51/1/)

```css
.item {
  height: 500px;
}

.svg-mask {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-with-mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  mask: url(#mask-wrapper);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <svg class="svg-mask" viewBox="0 0 256.4 77.5" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <image class="image-with-mask" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.nissan-cdn.net/content/dam/Nissan/nissan_europe/vehicles/gt-r/r35/2_minor_change/performance/17TDIeulhd_GTRHelios068.jpg.ximg.l_full_m.smart.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" x="0%" y="0%"></image>
  </svg>
</div>

<svg class="svg-defs" style="position: absolute;">
  <defs>
   <mask id="mask-wrapper" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <g fill="#fff" stroke="#fff">
     <path class="st0" d="M255.9,69C185.3,79.7,71.1,79.7,0.5,69"/>
     <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" class="st0" width="255.4" height="68.5"/>
    </g>
   </mask>
  </defs>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил добавить новый ответ, чтобы не смешивать два разных подхода.

В первом ответе я обращал ваше внимание, что браузеры неодинаково рассчитывают позиционирование. Поэтому в хроме была лишняя обрезка.

Второй момент - в Firefox'e были заметны ступеньки, так происходит при сильном увеличении растровой картинки.  Этот эффект возник потому-что вы натягивали маску шириной 200px на картинку шириной 1500px.
Чтобы избавиться от этих двух нежелательных дефектов сделаем следующее.

**Решение:**

- Перерисуем маску сравнимую по размерам с изображением

Открываем в векторном редакторе нужное изображение,

*но не встраиваем его, а связываем*, то есть в файле на выходе будет ссылка на это изображение:

`<image xlink:href="Nissan.jpg" />`

Рисуем путь, который обеспечивает нужную форму маски:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл в векторном редакторе и забираем из него патч, который будет основой нашей    маски.

Пишем код, реализующий маску

```
<mask id="mask-wrapper">
  <rect width="1500" height="843" fill="white" />
  <path  d="m -1.813209,790.41694 c 0,0 500.909929,58.02269 752.481749,58.02269 251.57186,0 752.48176,-58.02269 752.48176,-58.02269 L 1500,843 0,843 Z"  style="fill:black;stroke:black"/>
  </mask>
```

Белый прямоугольник в маске пропускает сквозь себя всё изображение, а черный полукруглый патч, вырезает нужную форму.

```html
<style>
.image-with-mask {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  mask: url(#mask-wrapper);
}
</style>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1500 843" version="1.1" id="svg2" border="1">
  
  <defs >
  <mask id="mask-wrapper">
  <rect width="1500" height="843" fill="white" />
  <path  d="m -1.813209,790.41694 c 0,0 500.909929,58.02269 752.481749,58.02269 251.57186,0 752.48176,-58.02269 752.48176,-58.02269 L 1500,843 0,843 Z"  style="fill:black;stroke:black"/>
  </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <image class="image-with-mask" xlink:href="https://www.nissan-cdn.net/content/dam/Nissan/nissan_europe/vehicles/gt-r/r35/2_minor_change/performance/17TDIeulhd_GTRHelios068.jpg.ximg.l_full_m.smart.jpg"  y="0" x="0" height="843" width="1500" />
  
</svg>
```

Изображение адаптивно к разному размеру экрана.

Если необходимо будет, как-то изменить размеры изображения, то изменяйте `width` `height` в **процентах** шапке svg

`width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1500 843"`

Comment: ого, я думаю это то что нужно, как найду время поразбираюсь, спасибо большое, с новым годом!

Comment: @артем и Вас С Новым годом! Желаю успехов, удачи во всем, творческих достижений.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так, это выглядит в Firefox`е:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё дело в том, что `Chrome` и `Firefox` несколько по разному относятся к позиционированию маски, клиппатча относительно окна браузера. 
Чтобы смотрелось одинаково во всех браузерах, я убрал стили, которые излишне влияют на позиционирование   и добавил команду:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
```

```html
<style>
.image-with-mask {
   mask: url(#mask-wrapper);
}
</style>
<div class="item">
  <svg class="svg-mask" width="100%"  height="100%"  viewBox="0 0 256.4 77.5" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <image class="image-with-mask" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.nissan-cdn.net/content/dam/Nissan/nissan_europe/vehicles/gt-r/r35/2_minor_change/performance/17TDIeulhd_GTRHelios068.jpg.ximg.l_full_m.smart.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" x="0%" y="0%"></image>
  </svg>
</div>

<svg class="svg-defs" style="position: absolute;">
  <defs>
   <mask id="mask-wrapper" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <g  stroke="#fff" fill="#fff">
     <path class="st0" d="M255.9,69C185.3,79.7,71.1,79.7,0.5,69" fill="white"/>
     <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" class="st0" width="255.4" height="68.5" fill="white"/>
    </g>
   </mask>
  </defs>
 </svg>
```

Работает во всех браузерах и даже в `IE`.

Comment: А возможно эту картинку растянуть на всю ширину окна, чтобы она также вместе с маской растянулась по высоте, а не просто обрезалась?

Comment: @артем Можно растянуть на весь экран, только будет ещё хуже выглядеть в Firefox. Обратите внимание на первый скрин в моем ответе. По краю картинки - ступеньки.  Нужно полностью переписать ваш файл, костыли не помогут. Сейчас у всех предновогодние хлопоты. Найду окошко свободного времени - сделаю. Заглядывайте почаще. Поздравляю Вас С наступающим Новым годом!