# При использовании SVG изображения в android приложении происходит потеря качества

Tags: android, svg

Непонятно почему(для меня непонятно), при использовании svg изображения происходит потеря качества изображения. Делал значок в illustrator.

Код SVG изображения

```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:28;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
     .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:44;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
     .st2{fill:#000000;}
    </style>
    <g>
     <line class="st0" x1="289.9" y1="285" x2="322.7" y2="317.9"/>
    </g>
    <path class="st1" d="M358,324.1l68.4,68.4c4.7,4.7,4.7,12.3,0,17l-13.4,13.4c-4.7,4.7-12.3,4.7-17,0l-68.4-68.4
     c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3,0-17l13.4-13.4C345.7,319.5,353.4,319.5,358,324.1z"/>
    <g>
     <path class="st2" d="M193.5,25C109.3,25,41,93.3,41,177.5S109.3,330,193.5,330S346,261.7,346,177.5S277.7,25,193.5,25z
       M193.5,299.5c-67.4,0-122-54.6-122-122s54.6-122,122-122s122,54.6,122,122S260.9,299.5,193.5,299.5z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

После преобразования в Vector asset(xml) получается следующий результат.
Смотреть на значок поиска.

[image: Смотреть на значок поиска]

Comment: Однако же при использовании инструмента стороннего, подобного размытия не наблюдается.

Comment: Почему не использовать png?Я лично использую png и больше вообще не о чем не думаю, зачем тебе вообще svg?

Comment: Почему не ешь репу?Я лично ем репу и больше вообще не о чем не думаю, зачем тебе вообще что-то еще?

Comment: Только без обид, это я утрировал, чтобы усилить понимание неконструктивизма позиции комментирующего. svg  обрел свою вторую молодость именно с появлением ретина экранов. Надо просто преодолеть снобизм и научиться  пользоваться SVG.

Comment: Для того чтоб правильно ответить на вопрос, нужно видеть уже преобразованный формат, vector drawable , это исключит ошибки при преобразовании. Второе, показать верстку или код, увидеть как вы сетите ресурс в элемент, это исключит ошибки неверного использования, + желательно показать настройки default config gradle , чтоб понять какой версией вы пользуетесь и подключена ли у вас поддержка support lib

Comment: в стандартном наборе VectorAssets Andrid Studio есть иконка лупы, которая выглядит, как и положено. Зачем рисовать свою и не понимать, что с ней не так, когда есть уже готовая и качественно сделаная?

Comment: @pavlofff может у человека аналитический склад ума и он хочет досконально разобраться сам.  Не с иконкой, так с другим изображением может повториться этот же эффект

Comment: У вас какой-то неправильный `svg` получился. Должны быть указаны размеры холста и иконки. При добавлении в **Androin Studio** не нажимайте галку "заоверрайдить размер". А вообще попробуйте использовать `SearchView` - это поле с иконкой лупы, специально для этих целей.

Comment: Эммм ... Зачем svg в android? Конвертируйте ее в vector drawable

Comment: Закройте этот вопрос, на него невозможно дать ответ без данных которые я попросил ваше.

Comment: @pavloff даже с готовым VD из студии можно легко так накосячить, нужно видеть что автор с ней делает, сейчас на вопрос невозможно дать ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте свою иконку в проект через **Vector Assets** и тогда не будет никаких проблем с отображением.

Ну и вообще конвертация обычно нужна, просто потому что **Android Studio** не все может скушать из того что выдает Иллюстратор в `svg`.

**ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНО**

Вот так будет выглядеть представленный вами код иконки после конвертации.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportHeight="500.0"
        android:viewportWidth="500.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M289.9,285L322.7,317.9"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeWidth="28"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M358,324.1l68.4,68.4c4.7,4.7 4.7,12.3 0,17l-13.4,13.4c-4.7,4.7 -12.3,4.7 -17,0l-68.4,-68.4c-4.7,-4.7 -4.7,-12.3 0,-17l13.4,-13.4C345.7,319.5 353.4,319.5 358,324.1z"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeWidth="44"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M193.5,25C109.3,25 41,93.3 41,177.5S109.3,330 193.5,330S346,261.7 346,177.5S277.7,25 193.5,25zM193.5,299.5c-67.4,0 -122,-54.6 -122,-122s54.6,-122 122,-122s122,54.6 122,122S260.9,299.5 193.5,299.5z"/>
</vector>
```

Размер указанный внутри векторной картинки, должен совпадать с размером изображения в макете. Например, если в макете у вас вью 40dp, то в самой картинке должно быть так же.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp"
        android:viewportHeight="500.0"
        android:viewportWidth="500.0">
    ...
</vector>
```

И вот так она буде выглядеть на устройстве. Без каких-либо артефактов. Идеально при любом разрешении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя конечно правильнее для таких вещей использовать стандартные, уже готовые векторные иконки из библиотеки.

Comment: на самом деле VectorDrawable не может скушать большую часть из стандарта svg

Comment: @pavlofff, не совсем. Он может скушать практически что угодно, при выполнении нескольких простых правил. Это не касается конкретно **Android Studio**, это в принципе правила корректной работы с вектором.

Comment: Но изображение не будет адаптивным. И при увеличении картинки, артефакты появятся, они никуда не делись. Я что хочу сказать, раз проблема не решена, то svg будет вести себя как png, то есть будет не масштабироваться, а просто увеличиваться в размерах. Решение тут одно, менять иконку, все беды в ней.или делать его действительно адаптивным, с подключением библиотеки Вот пост @Pavloff https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453166/28748

Comment: @Alexandr_T, все беды не в иконке, а в банальном незнании особенностей работы с вектором. Обновил картинку в ответе. Никаких библиотек не использовал.

Comment: @ kulikovman я надеюсь, что ваши слова о банальном незнании вектора, относятся не ко мне

Comment: Эти строки в VD не могут отсутствовать , иначе будет ошибка при компайле. Второе у вас сам VD его пафы и заливаются и обрисовываются жирной линией. И третье если вы создадите на любом устройстве ниже 21API , картинку к примеру 200х200 dp и вставите эту свг, она у вас  будет низкого качества, так как вы не используете библиотеку обратной совместимости. И в целом зачем отвечать на вопросы, если ответ невозможен по входным данным, там все что угодно мб, такие вопросы нужно закрыть на переработку

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, уже давно библиотека совместимости включена по умолчанию и вектор можно использовать на любых версиях API, начиная с третьей или четвертой.

Comment: Ага а вы её сетите srcCompat или src ? Там множество факторов, а знаете что в более низких версиях она в рантайме в растр переводится, а знаете какое правило перехода? да по viewPort учитывая density. Я повторю...зачем отвечать на вопросы, если ответ невозможен по входным данным, там все что угодно может происходить, такие вопросы нужно закрыть на переработку

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei А как нарисована иконка вообще не имеет значения - автор дал код, я показал как его использовать, чтобы все работало.

Comment: Автор дал код, там почему вы не использовали raw svg ? знаете что в Android можно из ассетов вставить svg ? И нарисованая иконка ещё как имеет значения, ибо во время ковертации, если взять например Scetch он пишет кучу хлама своего в Header, от этого зависит правильно сконвертированый VectorDrawable и опять же я могу повторить что автор вопроса не предоставил этой инофрмации

Comment: Спасибо большое, но есть вопрос. Каким образом вы конвертируете векторное изображение? Я и так добавлял через vector assets, но потеря качества произошла. Когда я конвертировал через другой инструмент(сайт), то потери качества такой не было, но артефакты остались тем не менее.

Comment: @Дмитрий, какой размер иконки у вас в макете?

Comment: @kulikovman 40 на 40

Comment: @Дмитрий, внутри вектора выставьте такой же размер, он должен совпадать. В ответ добавил пример.

Comment: @kulikovman Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Причинами такого поведения svg может быть совмещение нескольких причин:

- Вы нарисовали очень большую иконку `500 х 500px` и затем ваш гаджет,
  перед выводом на дисплей  сжимает иконку примерно в 16 раз.
  svg изображение теоретически не должно подвергаться размытости при изменении масштаба. Но на практике замечено, что svg прекрасно работает без потери качества при увеличении исходного изображения, но не всегда сохраняет качество при уменьшении масштаба.
- Всё зависит от качества прорисовки и знаний дизайнера, создающего иконку.
  Например в вашем случае,- вместо заполнения цветом ручки лупы использованы
  очень толстые линии, которые перекрывают друг друга. То же самое сделано в обводке самой лупы. 
  При изменении масштаба векторные линии увеличиваются, уменьшаются пропорционально, при этом ведут себя своеобразно,- половина толщины линии располагается внутри контура, вторая снаружи. При неблагоприятном выборе ширины линии появляются такие эффекты, как у вас.
- Вы не видели этой пикселизации на мониторе компьютера, потому-что
  недостаточно уменьшили масштаб.  Причем нужно смотреть в Firefox`e
  Последние версии Chrome научились сглаживать эти дефекты.

Пример с уменьшением масштаба в 16 раз

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="50%" height="50%"  viewBox="0 0 2000 2000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:28;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-width:44;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:#fff;}
</style>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#3D51B4" />
<g>
    <line class="st0" x1="289.9" y1="285" x2="322.7" y2="317.9"/>
</g>
<path class="st1" d="M358,324.1l68.4,68.4c4.7,4.7,4.7,12.3,0,17l-13.4,13.4c-4.7,4.7-12.3,4.7-17,0l-68.4-68.4
    c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3,0-17l13.4-13.4C345.7,319.5,353.4,319.5,358,324.1z"/>
<g>
    <path class="st2" d="M193.5,25C109.3,25,41,93.3,41,177.5S109.3,330,193.5,330S346,261.7,346,177.5S277.7,25,193.5,25z
         M193.5,299.5c-67.4,0-122-54.6-122-122s54.6-122,122-122s122,54.6,122,122S260.9,299.5,193.5,299.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Вот как это выглядит в FF при уменьшении окна браузера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На ретина дисплее будет выглядеть также, как у вас.

**Что можно посоветовать в вашем случае:**

- Выбирать готовые, стандартные svg иконки,  их нетрудно найти

. 
Принцип один,- чем меньше вес в байтах, тем более профессионально сделана иконка.

- Хочется сделать, что-то самому, выбирайте в векторном редакторе
  размер документа

  примерно равный размеру будущей иконки `32 х 32` `64 х 64` `128 x 128`
- Рисуйте по возможности только патчами.

В ваше примере попробуйте убрать масштабирование обводки линий командой

```
vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;
```

Ниже пример кода:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:28;stroke-miterlimit:10; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:54;stroke-miterlimit:10; vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke;}
    .st2{fill:#000000;}
</style>
<g>
    <line class="st0" x1="289.9" y1="285" x2="322.7" y2="317.9"/>
</g>
<path class="st1" d="M358,324.1l68.4,68.4c4.7,4.7,4.7,12.3,0,17l-13.4,13.4c-4.7,4.7-12.3,4.7-17,0l-68.4-68.4
    c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3,0-17l13.4-13.4C345.7,319.5,353.4,319.5,358,324.1z"/>
<g>
    <path class="st2" d="M193.5,25C109.3,25,41,93.3,41,177.5S109.3,330,193.5,330S346,261.7,346,177.5S277.7,25,193.5,25z
         M193.5,299.5c-67.4,0-122-54.6-122-122s54.6-122,122-122s122,54.6,122,122S260.9,299.5,193.5,299.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Update**

Пара иконок `search.svg`, попробуйте, может подойдёт в ваше приложение

```html
<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 48 48" enable-background="new 0 0 48 48">
    <g fill="#616161">
        <rect x="34.6" y="28.1" transform="matrix(.707 -.707 .707 .707 -15.154 36.586)" width="4" height="17"/>
        <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="16"/>
    </g>
    <rect x="36.2" y="32.1" transform="matrix(.707 -.707 .707 .707 -15.839 38.239)" fill="#37474F" width="4" height="12.3"/>
    <circle fill="#64B5F6" cx="20" cy="20" r="13"/>
    <path fill="#BBDEFB" d="M26.9,14.2c-1.7-2-4.2-3.2-6.9-3.2s-5.2,1.2-6.9,3.2c-0.4,0.4-0.3,1.1,0.1,1.4c0.4,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.4-0.1 C16,13.9,17.9,13,20,13s4,0.9,5.4,2.5c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.4c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,0.6-0.2C27.2,15.3,27.2,14.6,26.9,14.2z"/>
</svg>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" enable-background="new 0 0 32 32" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="search_1_">
 <path fill="#333333" d="M20,0.005c-6.627,0-12,5.373-12,12c0,2.026,0.507,3.933,1.395,5.608l-8.344,8.342l0.007,0.006
  C0.406,26.602,0,27.49,0,28.477c0,1.949,1.58,3.529,3.529,3.529c0.985,0,1.874-0.406,2.515-1.059l-0.002-0.002l8.341-8.34
  c1.676,0.891,3.586,1.4,5.617,1.4c6.627,0,12-5.373,12-12C32,5.378,26.627,0.005,20,0.005z M4.795,29.697
  c-0.322,0.334-0.768,0.543-1.266,0.543c-0.975,0-1.765-0.789-1.765-1.764c0-0.498,0.21-0.943,0.543-1.266l-0.009-0.008l8.066-8.066
  c0.705,0.951,1.545,1.791,2.494,2.498L4.795,29.697z M20,22.006c-5.522,0-10-4.479-10-10c0-5.522,4.478-10,10-10
  c5.521,0,10,4.478,10,10C30,17.527,25.521,22.006,20,22.006z"/>
 <path fill="#333333" d="M20,5.005c-3.867,0-7,3.134-7,7c0,0.276,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5s0.5-0.224,0.5-0.5c0-3.313,2.686-6,6-6
  c0.275,0,0.5-0.224,0.5-0.5S20.275,5.005,20,5.005z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Размер векторной иконки вообще не имеет значения и никак не связан с ее отображением.

Comment: @kulikovman теоретически да, но с привнесением данных, которые я подробно разобрал имеет.

Comment: @kulikovman Вот смотрите пример из практики -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765054/28748

Comment: Проблем о которых вы пишете нет. Все дело в правильном экспорте/импорте.

Comment: @kulikovman Вы думаете, что указав фиксированную ширину и высоту вы решили проблему? Нет, вы только сделали изображение не адаптивным.

Comment: Вы сначала проверьте как это работает ). В данном случае адаптивность зависит от количества пикселей, `dp` -  условная единица.

Comment: @kulikovman Чтобы сделать изображение действительно адаптивным нужно либо не указывать ширину и высоту `android:height="24dp"`  `android:width="24dp"`, либо указывать её в процентах, но это делается только с помощью подключения библиотеки  https://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/